# FDR-X1000V/W Sony Camera Remote API Beta SDK support

Tags: sony-camera-api

Does the FDR-X1000V/W 4k Action Cam support the Sony Camera Remote API Beta SDK?

It supports the LiveView remote so assuming it does.  Any details such as link to information is appreciated, did not come up in searching SDK site.

Answer (score 1):

Sony just published version 2.0 of the Sony Camera Remote API. The new version includes new API features and support for the 4K Action Cam **FDR-X1000** and the Full HD Action Cam **HDR-AS200**.

New API features are:

- **Loop recording.** Makes it possible to loop and overwrite recordings while existing files are kept securely.
- **Loop recording time**, which can be set to record for 5, 20, 60, 120, or unlimited minutes.
- **White balance.** Adds the possibility to automatically or manually adjust the color temperature. If you use the one push function, you can let the camera capture an image for a white balance custom setup.
- **Wind noise reduction.** Offers high-quality stereo sound recordings with less noise.
- **Audio recording setting.** Enables you to select and change the audio settings.

They posted [a blog post](https://developer.sony.com/2015/01/14/camera-remote-api-beta-updated-with-new-features-and-support-for-fdr-x1000-and-hdr-as200/) about the new release, which is the source of above information.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes. The Sony Camera Remote API Beta v2.30 offers rich support for the FDR-X1000:

[Download the API](https://developer.sony.com/downloads/all/sony-camera-remote-api-beta-sdk/), extract, then open document: Sony_CameraRemoteAPIbeta_API_Reference_v2.30.pdf

See page 11.

You can Start and Stop Recording, Change Movie Quality, transfer video and images, use Live View all over Wifi.